# Custom WM_APP message isn't posted in the message queue

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to send a custom message (WM_APP + 1) when WM_SIZE is send to the window procedure. I want to be able to catch it from an other function using PeekMessage and do somethings. But when I test it the messages seem to not be send to the queue. Adding some printf statements shows me that it goes to the window procedure. The weird thing is that when I step through the code in the debugger it works fine but when I'm running normally, it goes back to not working.

Working example program with the problem, resize the window to test:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

#define OBG_EVENT_QUIT 0
#define OBG_EVENT_RESIZE 1
#define OBG_EVENT_NO -1
#define OBG_EVENT_UNKNOWN -2

//user defined event
#define OBG_WM_RESIZE (WM_APP + 1)

typedef union
{
    int type;

    struct
    {
        int type;
        int width;
        int height;

    } resizeEvent;

} obg_event;

LRESULT CALLBACK obgpf_DefaultWindowCallback(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = 0;

    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            PostMessageA(window, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
        } break;

        //this should be handled by OBGGetEvent
        case OBG_WM_RESIZE:
        {
            printf("MESSAGE WENT THROUGH. DON'T WANT THIS\n");
        } break;

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            PostMessageA(window, OBG_WM_RESIZE, wParam, lParam);
        } break;

        default:
        {
            result = DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);
        } break;
    }

    return result;
}

int OBGGetEvent(obg_event *event)
{
    int moreMessages = 0;
    MSG message;

    if(PeekMessage(&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        moreMessages = 1;
        switch(message.message)
        {
            case WM_QUIT:
            {
                event->type = OBG_EVENT_QUIT;
            } break;


            case OBG_WM_RESIZE:
            {
                event->type = OBG_EVENT_RESIZE;
                event->resizeEvent.type = OBG_EVENT_RESIZE;
                event->resizeEvent.width = LOWORD(message.lParam);
                event->resizeEvent.height = HIWORD(message.lParam);
            } break;

            default:
            {
                event->type = OBG_EVENT_UNKNOWN;
                TranslateMessage(&message);
                DispatchMessage(&message);
            } break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        event->type = OBG_EVENT_NO;
    }

    return moreMessages;
}

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE instance = GetModuleHandleA(0);

    WNDCLASSEX windowClass = {0};
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(windowClass);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = obgpf_DefaultWindowCallback;
    windowClass.hInstance = instance;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "testClass";
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursorA(0, IDC_ARROW);

    HWND window;

    if(RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        window = CreateWindowEx(0,
                                windowClass.lpszClassName,
                                "test window",
                                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                500,
                                300,
                                0,
                                0,
                                instance,
                                0);

        if(window)
        {
            int appIsRunning = 1;
            obg_event event = {0};
            event.type = -1;
            while(appIsRunning)
            {
                while(OBGGetEvent(&event))
                {
                    if(event.type == OBG_EVENT_QUIT)
                    {
                        printf("event quit\n");
                        appIsRunning = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(event.type == OBG_EVENT_RESIZE)
                    {
                        printf("window resized: width %d height %d\n", event.resizeEvent.width, event.resizeEvent.height);
                    }
                }

                Sleep(33);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("window error\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("windowClass error\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried doing this with SendMessage instead of PeekMessage but the same thing happened. Not sure what I'm missing or misunderstanding but any help is appreciated!

EDIT: added a complete working program that reproduces the problem

Comment: You're posting `OBG_WM_MOVE` but looking for `OBG_WM_RESIZE`.

Comment: that was a typo sorry

Comment: It can't be a typo if you copy/paste your actual code instead of posting something else. If you want help with your code, post your actual code. And if you're trying to do something when you receive `WM_SIZE`,  then why aren't you just handling `WM_SIZE` directly instead of posting a different message and responding to it? `case WM_SIZE: DoYourStuffHere(); break;`

Comment: I didn't copy the code. Just rewrote a small part that is causing problems. The whole code just for these two functions is 300 lines long and most of it has no relation with the problem. I tried handling WM_SIZE in ProcessWindowMessages but it seems to go directly to the window procedure. And I want to handle it outside of the window procedure, this is a requirement. I have already though of a solution for this but its not clean and would rather avoid it. So I'm asking in case I'm misunderstanding something about PostMessage, PeekMessage or the message queue as a whole.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the fake code you've shown (now that you fixed the "typo"). If you show your real code maybe we can help you. If it's too big to post then try to create a [MCVE] that isn't too big.

Comment: My point was that you *should* copy the code, from the [mre] that you created for your question. Making up code on the fly is useless, because you can introduce new problems (like your typo) or fail to include something that is the actual cause of the problem. We require a [mre] because of that very reason. Making up code for your post is a waste of both your time and ours. It's frequently the case that when you create the [mre] in order to post it here you figure out what the problem is yourself and don't need to post after all.

Comment: Added a fully working example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the example code.

The behaviour you're seeing is because when the window is being resized using the mouse, the OS enters a modal message loop to process mouse input. During this loop, your message loop doesn't run - which means your `PeekMessage()` and the special message handling doesn't run either. Instead, messages are simply dispatched as normal to your window procedure.

There are two solutions that come to mind immediately but how you deal with this really depends on the design of your program and why you want to process size events in this way.

The first idea I had is to keep track of whether you're in a modal sizing loop or not, and defer posting the notification message until the loop is finished. An example of how to do that using your provided window procedure is below.

The second solution is to simply call your resize event handler directly whenever you get `WM_SIZE` (or, if you must go through the event system, put the handler for it in the window procedure rather than using `PostMessage`).

Example code for the first suggestion:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK obgpf_DefaultWindowCallback(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = 0;
    static bool fResized = false;
    static bool fInSizeLoop = false;

    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            PostMessageA(window, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
        } break;

        //this should be handled by OBGGetEvent
        case OBG_WM_RESIZE:
        {
            printf("MESSAGE WENT THROUGH. DON'T WANT THIS\n");
        } break;

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            if (fInSizeLoop) // in modal size loop, defer notification
                fResized = true;
            else
                PostMessageA(window, OBG_WM_RESIZE, wParam, lParam);
        } break;

        case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
            fInSizeLoop = true; // begin modal size loop
            break;

        case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
            fInSizeLoop = false; // left modal size loop
            // post resize notification now
            if (fResized) {
                RECT rc;
                GetClientRect(window, &rc);
                PostMessageA(window, OBG_WM_RESIZE, 0, MAKELPARAM(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top));
                fResized = false;
            }
            break;

        default:
        {
            result = DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);
        } break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

(sorry, this is C++ code and I just noticed you had tagged as C - but the principle is the same).